# Single MailCleaner installation for two distinct domains with user authentication

Tags: active-directory, email, spam

I would like to use one MailCleaner installation to handle two distinct domains as one centralised spam management system, sharing configuration and mainly the bayesian filtering database. Both domains have their own Active Directory on different locations, and both AD servers are inside the LAN. So there's no remote access from the WAN.

The main problem is to setup authentication on those two domains, but I'm unable to connect to the Domain Controllers because they are protected inside the LAN. I've read about Master/Slave configuration from MailCleaner, but I wasn't able to understood if this fits in my scenario, it appears to only support Failover.

Another idea is to install a RODC (Read Only Domain Controller) in both domains to talk through the WAN. I don't know if it's a good practice of not. I'm just trying to figure out how to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not access to your AD from outside, you can configure the user authentication with IMAP or SMTP

The clustering of MailCleaner will not help you in this situation, it is just for load balancing and redundancy